# My asp.net 1.1 site will not refresh

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-5, asp.net-1.1, windows-2000

I have an ASP.NET **1.1** site and I'm uploading a small change, but the page will not refresh. The page was changed 2.5 hours ago. I have tried loading the page in 3 different browsers, so I know the issue is not browser caching. I searched for similar situations on the web and StackOverflow. I have tried changing the query string, deleting the file and uploading again, and changing web.config to try to force a site restart.

I even uploaded the file under a different name to make sure there was not another problem. That did work, but I don't want to change all of the links to point to a new page. I even tried using Remote Desktop to log into another computer at another client to check if the cached version of the page is there too... it is.

The site is co-located using shared hosting, and my (new) client doesn't even know how to find the URL for the administrator's panel or who to call for support.

Using [Whats that site running?](http://www.netcraft.com/whats), I found out what the server is running:

> Windows 2000
>   Microsoft-IIS/5.0
>   ASP.NET v1.1
>   F5 Big-IP

I know! Crummy host!

I'm sure in a day or so I'll contact support and clear this up, but I'll still want to know how this page is cached. I have been programming ASP.NET for 5 years and don't remember anything like this before. I don't think there is a proxy caching the page, but so far that is the only thing I can think of.

Thanks for any ideas in advance...

EDIT: Code sample... This appears to be a single page ASPX page, no code behind.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using a precompiled/code behind site, and not updating the bin directory?

Have you published with "allow this precompiled site to be updatable" checked?

Comment: No, this is not a precompiled site. It looks like the previous dev is using an ASPX page just so include files could be used. Since it is a ASP.NET 1.1 site, MasterPages are not available.

Comment: Are sure there's not another host? the Big-IP would suggest a web farm & the file coming off a host other than the one you're changing

Comment: Make sure you are 100% you have the right site. Add something into the root - a picture or an html file or something. Ping it and check that you can download that file.

Comment: Sometimes you (or the webhost) might have to clear the Temporary ASP.NET Files directory located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[Version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

If it's not patched, then it could suffer from an old bug where the Temporary ASP.NET Files aren't updated correctly.

If that's the case, be glad it went wrong this way - it can also go wrong in such a way as to throw compilation bugs on random pages throughout your application. If that's the case then restarting may be required. Or worse, stopping, clearing that directory, and then starting.

For both this, and some other compilation mis-fires, you could try introducing a null change (add a space, delete the space) to the global.asax. This can trigger an entire recompilation.